# How to use slick-slider in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, slick.js

I have slick-slider

```
    <div class="slider">
      <div><img src="img/seasons/spring.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div><img src="img/seasons/summer.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div><img src="img/seasons/winter.jpg" alt=""></div>
    </div>
```

**Js**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.slider').slick({
            dots: true,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 500,
            fade: true,
            cssEase: 'linear',
            autoplay:true,
            adaptiveHeight:true,

        });
    });
```

And it works well anywhere,but I need to use this slider in block and it doesn't work here

```
<div ng-repeat="forecast in forecasts.list" class="forecast"> 
  <p>{{ forecast.dt_txt}}</p>
  <button ng-click="toggle = !toggle">Go</button>
  <div ng-show="toggle">
    <div class="slider">
      <div><img src="img/seasons/spring.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div><img src="img/seasons/summer.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div><img src="img/seasons/winter.jpg" alt=""></div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

How to fix ?

Comment: Simple use the angular slick slider from https://github.com/devmark/angular-slick-carousel here

Comment: I thought about this,but i have misunderstanding with it so..I can't use slick without this plug in AnuglarJs?